# Как в php изменить поле объекта одного класса через метод другого класса

Tags: php, ооп

```
class a{
    public $k;
}
$var = new a();
class b{
    function c(){
        $a->k=2;
    }
}
```

В метод 'c' я принимаю параметры через api. Мне нужно менять значение 'k' у объекта 'var'. В данном случае мне нужно полю 'k' объекта 'var' присвоить '2'. Но имею ошибку:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: В метод c вы никакие параметры не принимаете

Comment: Я не написал весь код. Мне просто нужно изменить поле k у объекта a в этом методе

Comment: В предоставленном коде экземпляр класса `b` не имеет никакого понятия откуда взялась переменная `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

Оно?

```
<?php

class A{
    public $k;
}

class B{

    function c(){
        $linkA = new A();
        echo $linkA->k=2;

    }
}
    
$linkB = new B();
$linkB->c();
```